# Laplacian eigenvalue problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I'm working through a PDE problem and we are given the eigenvalue problem $-\Delta u = \lambda u$ with $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0$ along the boundary given by the rectangle $\Omega = (0, \pi)$ x $(0, \pi)$, where $n$ is the outward normal.  Using divergence theorem I can show that $\int_{C} \lambda \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0$, but I'm not sure how that helps me...

Comment: That somehow verifies the first eigenvalue of the Neumann Laplacian on simply-connected domain is zero. For this problem, is a square domain, you can actually use separation of variables to tackle this problem.

Comment: How do I use the boundary condition given though? It's given along the normal so it seems like I should use divergence theorem

Comment: Separation of variable will use for sure. The normal derivative on four edges of the square is nothing but $\pm\partial_x u$ or $\pm\partial_y u$.

Comment: What does it mean by prove all eigenvalues are real though?

Comment: As in, isn't $\lambda$ given?  Isn't the problem solvable for all values of $\lambda$?

Comment: You are looking for all possible values of $\lambda$, see what values are admissible for such problems has a unique solution. A hint is first letting $u(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$, plugging back the equation and boundary conditions on four sides, see what $f$ and $g$ should satisfy.